# Why healpy is not visualization my polarization cmb map?

Tags: dictionary, healpy, cls, polarization

I want to compute the power spectrum of  a polarization cmb map with a mask. In previous steps  I used healpy to visualize a polarization smica map, it returns  a error message "  Wrong pixel number (it is not 12*nside**2)" when it is map downloaded from esa planck data.

## Import libraries

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp 
import pymaster as nmt
```

## read map

```
pol_map=hp.read_map('/home/akozameh/COM_CMB_IQU-smica_2048_R3.00_hm2.fits', (1,2))
hp.mollview(pol_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize just one component at a time
So you should just visualize either Q or U